# C++ query of JSON subObject error

Tags: c++, json, deserialization

my code compiles without error but at runtime I get the following error ->

```
testGetprice2.o: rapidjson/include/rapidjson/document.h:1125: rapidjson::SizeType rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::Size() const [with Encoding = rapidjson::UTF8<>; Allocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>; rapidjson::SizeType = unsigned int]: Assertion `IsArray()' failed.
```

where it is failing is in my for () loop

```
std::cout << document[i]["lasttradeprice"].
```

I am trying to query for the subObject "lasttradeprice" but clearly accessing the object incorrectly.

How do I query the subobject correctly/get rid of this error?

code ->

```
#include "rapidjson/include/rapidjson/document.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

using namespace rapidjson;

struct myData
{
    std::fstream *file;
    std::string *str;
};

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, myData *data)
{
    size_t numBytes = size * nmemb;

    if (data->file)
        data->file->write((char*)ptr, numBytes);

    if (data->str)
        *data->str += std::string((char*)ptr, numBytes);

    return numBytes;
}

//function to get coin data and perform analysis
int getData()
{
    int count = 0;

    //begin non terminating loop
    while(true)
    {
        count++;
        CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
        if (curl)
        {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=singlemarketdata&marketid=155");

            std::fstream file("/home/coinz/cryptsy/myfile.txt", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::ate);
            std::string json;

            myData data;
            data.file = &file;
            data.str = &json;

            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &write_data);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &data);

            /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
            CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

            /* Check for errors */
            if (res != CURLE_OK)
            {
                std::cerr << "curl_easy_perform() failed: " << curl_easy_strerror(res) << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                file << std::endl;

                //begin deserialization
                Document document;
                document.Parse(json.c_str());
                for (SizeType i = 0; i < document.Size(); i++){
                    std::cout << document[i]["lasttradeprice"].GetString() << std::endl;
                }
                //assert(document.HasMember("return"));
                //assert(document["return"].IsString());
                //std::cout << "The Last Traded Price is = " << document["return"].GetString() << std::endl;
            }

            /* always cleanup */
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        }

        //timer for URL request.  *ADUJST ME AS DESIRED*
        usleep(10000000);
    }

    return 0;
}

//Le Main
int main(void)
{
    getData();
}
```

gdb ->

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/coinz/cryptsy/testGetprice2.o
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for linux-vdso.so.1.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7ffff5cc9700 (LWP 24708)]
[Thread 0x7ffff5cc9700 (LWP 24708) exited]
testGetprice2.o: rapidjson/include/rapidjson/document.h:1125: rapidjson::SizeType rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::Size() const [with Encoding = rapidjson::UTF8<>; Allocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>; rapidjson::SizeType = unsigned int]: Assertion `IsArray()' failed.

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff6fec795 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Comment: You can't come up with a minimal example? Remove CURL from the equation? Remove the external data retrieval requirement? Remove that loop and sleep? Post a ten-line testcase?

Comment: I can pull level one data, just not 3 levels or even second. Nowhere can I find a valid parse sample of a subobject.

Comment: I thought I was able to access a single level object data but right now I cannot recreate this. http://miloyip.github.io/rapidjson/md_doc_tutorial.html#QueryValue

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what you're saying. Your phrasing is very unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your loop with

std::cout << "The Last Traded Price is = " << document["return"]["markets"]["DRK"]["lasttrad
eprice"].GetString() << std::endl;

Answer (score 0):

According to the original JSON the structure is the following:

```
{
  "success":1,
  "return":
  {
    "markets":
    {
      "DRK":
      {
        "marketid":"155",
        "label":"DRK\/BTC",
        "lasttradeprice":"0.00553336",
        "volume":"14615.30200941",
        "lasttradetime":"2014-10-25 14:35:09",
        "primaryname":"DarkCoin",
        "primarycode":"DRK",
        "secondaryname":"BitCoin",
        "secondarycode":"BTC",
        "recenttrades":
```

You are tying to access

```
document[i]["lasttradeprice"]
```

but you should access

```
documents["return"]["markets"][i]["lasttradedprice"]
```

Comment: I tried std::cout << document["return"]["markets
"]["DRK"][i]["lasttradeprice"].GetString() << std::endl; and I tried std::cout << document["return"]["markets
"][i]["lasttradeprice"].GetString() << std::endl;  and get the same error